# XSLT for Conditional rendering into html

Tags: xslt, altova

I have a fragment of XML that I want to render into html so that every tag   turns to a line break and other similar conditional escape sequences are rendered into tabs or carriage returns etc. Is there a way to do this in StyleVision 2015 Enterprise or any other tool. Can you give me an example please.

```
<OBX.5>
    <escape V=".br"/>Swee Tan
    <escape V=".br"/>ZMC Number:
    <escape V=".br"/>14834
    <escape V=".br"/>HI Number:
    <escape V=".br"/>10HQF
    <escape V=".br"/>Specialist's Signature:
    <escape V=".br"/>
    <escape V=".br"/>Date Signed:
    <escape V=".br"/>21.09.2014
    <escape V=".br"/>
    <escape V=".br"/>
</OBX.5>
```

Comment: Could you post your expected output? Also clarify what you mean by "other similar conditional escape sequences". I don't anything conditional here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML transform for escape sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188519/xml-transform-for-escape-sequences)